# MPMoviePlayerViewController Orientation Permission

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Might this is duplicated one, but I am not getting exactly what I want.

My application is only Portrait base and in which I want to show a **Video** file in **MPMoviePlayerViewController** only and only in **Landscape** mode. but unable to do that.

I've set my device orientation only **Portrait** and in which I wanna show movie direct in **landscape** mode. If any one did it then share it with me....thanks in advance

> ## Is it possible once I defined my app is only in Portrait mode(through PLIST/ Development Info setting) and then I want to change Orientation from programing(ex. Landscape mode).???

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked before, but the orientation/status bar APIs have changed enough in recent SDKs that asking is OK, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

In the project file, make sure you are supporting the Landscape Orientations

Now in all of your ViewControllers that should still be Portrait Only, add this code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

When your MPMoviePlayerController view becomes fullscreen, it will be a new ViewController layered on top of everything else. So, it will be allowed to rotate according to the Supported Interface Orientations of the Project. It will not see where you forced the other ViewControllers into Portrait.

Comment: I dont want to supporting the Landscape Orientations to my app. only wanted to show MPMoviePlayerViewController in landscape mode without changing the other Orientation supporting. because it will reduce my efforts if it is possible